# how to add providers and aliases to laravel app which is in production on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, cpanel

I want to add 2 providers and aliases to my laravel app .
but when I do this in a normal way i.e. going to config/app.php and add them to providers and aliases section.

The error is displayed that

> service provider not found

I have cpanel version 60.0.32 .Also  composer can't be installed on the server so there is no medium to run composer commands.

Comment: I faced a similar situation with Hostgator but I found a solution by doing what I mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing composer through curl. I faced the same issue and I did this.

Once I `clone` the repository, I `cd` in to it and did a

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then I ran `whereis php` to check available php versions. In my case the default php cli was php5.4 (output of `php -v`) but I needed php5.6. Then I did

```
/opt/php56/bin/php composer.phar install
```

to install dependencies.

That's it. If I want to use composer I used `/opt/php56/bin/php composer.phar` since.

Comment: @YaSh Chaudhary you need to ssh into your server and by using the terminal enter above commands

Answer (score -2):

You need to run composer first to pull or install your dependencies

Comment: He said he can't install composer on his server, so it's a bit hard to run composer.

Comment: @RobertoGeuke My answer is on the service provider not found, and also composer is required in laravel so my other plan in situation like that is to deploy the app in VPS, i dont deploy my laravel projects in shared hosting

Comment: Try to explain why he should use a VPS and why Composer is required in Laravel. This answer won't help anyone.